# Shared Lib: remove unused Symbol

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

I want to build a shared library.
Cross-Compilation isn't easy for this one, so i want to remove all unneeded functions during compilation (gcc) & linking (ld).

In executable programs with a main() you can remove unused functions with

- C_FLAGS = -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
- LD_FLAGS = --gc-sections

With this flags, GCC only keeps functions that are reachable from main.

Obviously, you don't have a main() in a shared library.
But, is there a way to tell GCC which functions are definitely needed for dynamic linking?
GCC could then build a call-tree from this functions and remove all others which are unreachable from there.

Is this possible?
Which GCC Flags are needed?

Comment: Make the symbols you definitely need *visible* and the rest *hidden*. (Pass `-fvisibility=hidden` and mark visible symbols with `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))`). This is a goid practice regardless. The linker will start building a call tree for GC with the set of visible symbols.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix-symbol-visibility/

Comment: @n.m. This should be an answer.